# Bash sed non-greedy matching

Tags: bash, sed, non-greedy

Here is my text:

```
1a.begin /path/1a.file
2bx.begin2 /path/my/2bx.file2
```

and the expected output is

```
begin /path/1a.file
begin2 /path/my/2bx.file2
```

Here I want to do it by using non-greedy matching by sed. (The default matching by sed is greedy and all the 1a. and 2bx. will be removed)

Hence I tried the command:

```
echo -e "1a.begin /path/1a.file\n2bx.begin2 /path/my/2bx.file2"|sed 's/$.*[^\.]\.//g'
```

where I used the `$.*` to match all strings starting at the head of a line. I used `[^\.]` to prevent greedy matching all `.` in a line (see similar method in https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/133641-non-greedy-sed.html)
But it did not change the text.

So where is my script wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Your start of line anchor `$` is wrong, you should be using `^`
- You use a greedy match `.*` up to the last period `.`

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^[^.]*\.//' input_file
begin /path/1a.file
begin2 /path/my/2bx.file2
```